# When called oauth.getAuthCredentials() the IOS app Will Logout

Tags: salesforce1-app

logged into the app using a username and password and allowed the permission, then the app synced and came to the home page after the sync was complete. when the user loses the app and reopens it the app will logout and redirect to the logging page with this error message
"SFOauthReactBridge.getAuthCredentials failed: {"message":"Not authenticated"}".

this is my get profile method it will call when the app is loading

```
**const getProfile = () => async dispatch => {
  /**
   * This function get profile from salesforce
   */
  try {
    dispatch({ type: START_LOADING_PROFILE });
    try {
      const auth = oauth.getAuthCredentials(); 
      if (config.debug) console.log('auth profile', auth);
      /**Wait until user Data Dispatch to redux Store */
     await dispatch({ type: FINISH_LOADING_PROFILE, payload: auth });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: ERROR_LOADING_PROFILE, payload: err });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (config.debug) console.log('catch profile Error', e);
    dispatch({ type: ERROR_LOADING_PROFILE, payload: e });
  }
};**
```

Comment: Tags are meant to tell people what the question is about. I don't see anything here indicating that it's about salesforceDX, react, or communities (experience sites).